# How to show button in center of toolbar?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, toolbar

I want to show button on top of and in center of Toolbar. I set the image of UIBarButtonItem but it does not give desired result as given in below image.

I am able to add Menu and Locate Me

but **could not add Request Button** as shown in pic.

Request BUtton is an image and when I set it the UIBarButtonItem image it gets stretched

please help

This is what I have done.
[image]

But I want to do this. as You can see that in my solution Request button is under toolbar and in the below pic Request button is on top.
[image]

Comment: here you want to display these two button in center and for that just add `UIBarButtonItem` with type `UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace` so its adjust both side with buttons and set these buttons to center see my answer.. :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

just add `UIBarButtonItem` with `FlexibleSpace` to both side of these two button like bellow..

```
UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace =  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
```

See all code with two buttons..

```
UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace =  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

UIBarButtonItem *locateMe = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(locateMe:)];

UIBarButtonItem *request = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(request:)];

UIBarButtonItem *menu = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(menu:)];

NSArray *toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:locateMe,flexibleSpace,request , flexibleSpace, menu];

[toolBar setItems:toolbarItems animated:NO];
```

From `XIB` you can also set this `UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace` like in bellow image..

[image]

**UPDATE:** you want to Add that request button with that image on UIToolBar then just bring that `UIImageView` and button after add `UIToolBar` on the `UIView` like bellow..

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:imgView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:btnRequest];
```

Comment: @NG_SE i know that you have only two buttons on the toolbar right?? so i write exact code which you want :)

Comment: @Paras.. I need solution for middle button

Comment: @NG_SE yes now see updated answer , also you add that request button in toolbar or not??

Comment: @ParasJoshi you getting wrong ane Middel button bigger joiche like i posted demo link and image

Comment: yes i know dude so waiting for NG_SE reply that he add this in toolbar or not

Comment: @NG_SE just set that flwxibleSpace between that 3 buttons like my updated above code

Answer (score 3):

From Nib use *flexible space item on a `UIToolbar` object*. like bellow Image:-

[image]

For Adding center Button Bigger then ToolBar Hight then check this bellow Demo and use Its' category for doing this Task just Drag you image into demo and change image name to CenterButtonIconPaw.png and check:-

https://github.com/el-eleven/EEToolbarCenterButton

using your image i done as you want It's Look like similar to your Need:-

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

Swift version

```
    let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(
                        barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace,
                        target: nil,
                        action: nil)

    let locateMe = UIBarButtonItem(
                        barButtonSystemItem: .plain,
                        target: self,
                        action: #selector(locateMe))

    let request = UIBarButtonItem(
                        barButtonSystemItem: .plain,
                        target: self,
                        action: #selector(request))

    let menu = UIBarButtonItem(
                        barButtonSystemItem: .plain,
                        target: self,
                        action: #selector(menu))

    let items = [locateMe, flexibleSpace, request, flexibleSpace, menu]

    setToolbarItems(items, animated: false)
```