# IOS - Add button in tool bar left and middle

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I want to create a UI tool bar with effect like this

[DONE]-------[MINUS]--------

button DONE locate at left and button MINUS locate at middle

this is my code but I didn't get the button MINUS set to middle

```
UIToolbar* mtbKeyboardAccessoryView = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
[mtbKeyboardAccessoryView sizeToFit];

UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(doneKeyboard)];

UIBarButtonItem *minusBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"MINUS" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(minusSign)];

UIBarButtonItem *flexibleItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target: nil action: nil];

[mtbKeyboardAccessoryView setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:doneBtn, flexibleItem, minusBtn, flexibleItem, flexibleItem, nil]];
```

I don't want to create button with frame and customary set (w, h, x, y) and add sub-view to UI tool bar

Is that any way to set the UI bar button at left and middle and without affect the button coordinate when change orientation in landscape and portrait

I get a result like this
[DONE]-------[MINUS]-------------------
which minus button not set to middle

Comment: Have you tried adding a single flexible item after `minusBtn`? They are, after all, flexible ;)

Comment: Can you show your output in screenshot?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969260/how-to-show-button-in-center-of-toolbar this is what you want.

Comment: tried already the minus button also not locate in middle, 
it was like this done----------minus-----

Comment: my account is new unable to upload image sorry about that

Comment: @Mitesh Dobareeya the solution you are showing I also able to do it, because it have 3 button and the flexible space item will automatic adjust the mid button to middle, mine just have two button so the middle button will bent toward left or right =(

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Add UIBarButton for Done than add FlexibleItem than another UIBarButton for Minus and again add FlexibleItem.

Try to add this above..!! May this will help you..!!

Comment: doneBtn, flexibleItem, minusBtn, flexibleItem, flexibleItem,

look at my code above I already do it, but still not in the middle yet

Comment: Why you are adding two flexibleitem after minusBtn ? Try with one flexibleitem.

Comment: Ya I have added 1, but the minus button not aligned well at middle, but it's more toward to the right

Comment: I have toolbar like this <done>-----<minus>-----<next>
after that i removed next I got this, the wrong toolbar with wrong alignment <done>---------<minus>-----

Comment: Than try to add FixedISpaceBarButtonItem instead of last FlexibleItem i.e doneBtn, flexibleItem, minusBtn, flexibleItem, FixedISpaceBarButtonItem

Comment: I tried fixed space it need you to set width for it but when I turn to landscape it get messed up

Comment: Ohh..Your app is in both orientation..?

Comment: Ya, my senior told me he able to solved it just used flexible and fixed space, he ask me think it, but i tried very hard still did't get answer, he say no need update width in orientation change

Comment: Okay..If you get any proper answer or solution from your senior than please post it  as your answer. So if anybody stuck in same scenario, than he/ she will get solution :)

Comment: He never tell me solution, he say he use a very basic way to do it, I am a worker under his supervision, he will never tell me solution, when i fail to solved it I get trouble

Comment: Than, can you able to show me your view's screenshot which you have done. So I can able to find its solution.

Comment: my acc not able to upload image since my point is low
it's like this <done>-----<minus>----- the minus button locate exactly at the middle, when the <next> button is removed, it's the result expected