# Change the title color of keyboard toolbar objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uibarbuttonitem

I want to change the title color of keyboard `toobar` i.e(submit button), and the other is how can I add the image for keyboard toolbar. TIA

```
UIToolbar *keyboardToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];

[keyboardToolbar sizeToFit];

keyboardToolbar.translucent=NO; //if you want it.

keyboardToolbar.barTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

_txtCommentView.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolbar;

keyboardToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Submit" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(submitClicked:)],
                              nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the change in whole application Toolbar then Use

```
[UIToolbar appearance].tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
[UIToolbar appearance].barTintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Also you can Use below code to change :

```
 NSDictionary *attributes = @{
                                 NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor colorWithRed:220.0/255.0 green:104.0/255.0 blue:1.0/255.0 alpha:1.0],

                                 NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16.0]
                                 };
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: how to set the button to center

Comment: Add this 
UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace =  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
Check this Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969260/how-to-show-button-in-center-of-toolbar

Answer (score 1):

Try below code and do changes as per your requirement:

```
UIToolbar *keyboardToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];

[keyboardToolbar sizeToFit];

keyboardToolbar.translucent=NO; //if you want it.

keyboardToolbar.barTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

_txtCommentView.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolbar;


UIBarButtonItem *submit = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Submit"
                                                              style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                             target:self action:@selector(submitClicked:)];

//Change submit button attributes here as you want
[submit setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:18.0], NSFontAttributeName,
                                   [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                                   nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

keyboardToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:submit, nil];
```